# How to keep active css style after pressing the button

Tags: vue.js

I can only show the effect when pressing the button. When your click leave the button, it will disappear. I search some sample, people use addEventListen and directly btn.style.color=""[(ref)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Fw3jE0tWn28&t=197s) or use btnEl.classList.add( ) to apply the style[(ref)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zh1xus05Kl8&t=195s). However, I am using vue it should be @click="activeChoice". I am not very fimilar to vue , could anyone tell me how can I do the above operation in vue?

Code:

```
.button-text:active {
  color: white;
  background-color: #255390;
  border-radius: 3.125rem;
}

.choice:active {
  color: white;
  background-color: #255390;
}
```

Target:
[image: design]

My work:
[image: my work]

Answer (score 0):

You could add a class that has active styles in css and add it to the button only when you have clicked on it
your template would be as follows

```
<template>
<button class="normal-class-that-will-always-be-present" :class="isButtonClicked && 'active-class'" @click="myClickFn">click here</button>
</template>
```

your script, depending on whether you use composition or options api would be

```
<script>
export default {
...
data() {
return {
...other,
isButtonClicked: false,
},
},
methods: {
...,
myClickFn() {
// other stuff
this.isButtonClicked = true;
},
},
};
</script>
```

if you are using script setup

```
<script setup>
import { ref } from "vue";
const isButtonClicked = ref(false);
const myClickFn = () => {
// do other stuff
isButtonClicked.value = true; 
}
</script>
```

This is strictly if you want to only toggle class of a single button on click

in your case, i imagine you would need to select an item and keep the active class on whichever tab is open, so i would go like this

```
<template>
<button class="normal-class" :class="selectedTab === 'tab1' && 'active'" @click="selectTab('tab1')">Tab 1</button>

<button class="normal-class" :class="selectedTab === 'tab2' && 'active'" @click="selectTab('tab2')">Tab 2</button>
</template>
```

in your script you would go as

```
<script>
export default {
...,
data() {
return {
selectedTab: "tab1", // default
},
methods: {
selectTab(newTab) {
this.selectedTab = newTab;
}
}
}

}
</script>
```

or with setup

```
<script setup>
import {ref} from "vue";
const selectedTab = ref("tab1")// again default value
function selectTab(newTab) {
selectedTab.value = newTab;
}

</script>
```

Now whichever button is clicked will get the active class and it will be removed from the other button
ideally you would loop over the buttons instead of making them one by one but this is just easier to explain

Comment: I am using the script and successful set the state of isButtonClicked, but how to set my css to that clicked button to change the background & text color? I saw your code is :class="isButtonClicked && 'active-class',  what is the active-class use for?

Answer (score 0):

Final Ans(Solved):

Add the class **active** when activeIndex = the btn order, give a active class to it. The on click event copy the btn order to activeIndex as value. Then, when you press the button it will be active. Finally, just add the effect for it in css (having 2 classes **.button-text** & **.active** at the same time).

Template:

```
// Loop labels
<swiper-slide
  v-for="(label, index) in labels"
  :key="index"
  @click="handleActiveLabel(index)"
>
  <button 
    class="button-text" 
    :class="{ active: activeLabel == index }"  // New Added
  >
    {{ label.type }}
  </button>
</swiper-slide>


// Choices (Row2)
<div class="choice-list">
  <button
    class="choice"
    v-for="(choice, index) in labels[activeLabel].choice"
    :key="index"
    @click="handleActiveChoice(index)"
    :class="{ active: activeChoice == index }"
  >
    {{ choice }}
  </button>
</div>
```

Script:

```
export default {
  setup() {
    // Set ActiveIndex for showing choices
    const activeLabel = ref(0);
    const handleActiveLabel = (index) => {
      activeLabel.value = index; // Able to active the btns
      activeChoice.value = 0; // Reset choice, when switch label
    };

    const activeChoice = ref(0);
    const handleActiveChoice = (index) => {
     activeChoice.value = index; // Able to active the btns
    };

    return {
      activeLabel,
      handleActiveLabel,
      activeChoice,
      handleActiveChoice,
    }
  },
};
```

CSS:

```
// Active button's effect  
.button-text.active {
  color: white;
  background-color: #255390;
  border-radius: 3.125rem;
}

.choice.active {
  color: white;
  background-color: #255390;
}
```

Result:
[image]